# How can I fix a Laravel Mix build error in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-7

Working with Laravel 7 my resources->sass->app.scss is like the following:

```
@import "variables";

@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma";

@import "node_modules/buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

However, Laravel mix returns a build error here like

> ModuleBuild Error Module build faild (from./node module
> /saas-loader/dist/cjs.js);\rSaasError:cant find stylesheet to
> import.\r' @import "variables";

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `_variables.scss`, then remove the reference. This is the right way to reference the `/node_modules` directory.

```
// Fontawesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';

// Bulma
@import '~bulma/bulma';

// Buefy
@import '~buefy/src/scss/buefy';
```

Comment: I have not variables.scss file in your mentioned path. what are contents of it?

Comment: Remove @import 'variables'; from the scss file then.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually created the variables.scss file?

Laravel doesn't create this by default unless you run one of laravel/ui presets: bootstrap, vue, react